# Django problems with id in custom UserModel

Tags: django, django-admin, django-users

I need to use user_id instead id in my custom user model(don't ask why, it's a long story :)).
I try to use code from django example, but when it I tried to log in into admin backend, I got
In template site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html, error at line 60
'User' object has no attribute 'id'

Line with error looks like

```
{% get_admin_log 10 as admin_log for_user user %}


#UserManager
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, login_name, email, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = UserManager.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(login_name=login_name, email=email,     
        first_name=first_name,
        last_name=last_name,
                      is_staff=False, is_active=True, is_superuser=True)

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, login_name, email, first_name, last_name, password):
    u = self.create_user(login_name, email, first_name, last_name, password)
    u.is_staff = True
    u.is_active = True
    u.is_superuser = True
    u.save(using=self._db)
    return u

#Model
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    login_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, db_index=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    objects = UserManager()
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'login_name'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    is_staff = models.BooleanField('staff status', default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField('active', default=True)

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

#Admin
from django.contrib import admin
from applications.users.models import User


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('login_name', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Would be helpful to post your User model and what you did to use 'user_id' as the unique field.

Comment: how is your backend model defined ?

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/log.py This is where it is failing. Did you add the `user_id` recently ? If so, just clear the pyc files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem too. Looks like this was a bug in Django.  Thanks to @karthikr for pointing me towards the source (use the source luke!), but it looks like Django 1.5's admin has a hard-coded use of the "id" field, which of course may not exist if you've customised your user model.

Here's the commit in which they fix it:

https://github.com/django/django/commit/054ce2aa02c88221ffa5665a4b9a5739cbbd0a39

Looks like the fix is only available in version 1.6 though, so I guess the solution is to upgrade!

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this. I can sleep at night now knowing why my custom user model is exploding in the admin.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution:

Try this hack, it might work:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ...
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name='id':
            return self.user_id
        return self.__dict__[name]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, it doesn't help(
I also tried to use @property with your code, but I get an error: 'Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field'

Comment: Ok, heres a thought. Are you willing to do the monkey patching backwards? Use id as the key and do user_id as a property?

Comment: I have user_id field in my production database

Comment: I changed my answer with a hack that might work, overriding the `__getattr__` to deceive the `.id` field accesor, can you try?

Comment: Ok, I try and get again the same error.
But I see, that interpreter enter in if == 'id' in __getattr__

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31412/discussion-between-paulo-bu-and-ant)